# Sort array of object with another array of strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, sorting

I'm creating a chat with firestore.
I want to sort a array based on another array that has strings that are represented by the uid present on the first array.

first I have this state and this ID.

```
const [allInp, setAllInp] = useState({ searchConv: '' })
const dropId = searchConv
```

I have this array

```
const findUser = (ele) => {
    if (!ele || !ele.fullName) return false
    return ele.fullName.toLowerCase().includes(allInp[dropId].toLowerCase())
}
const myUid = 'ibPlTju8K2d3PlydP6sdm2T4S2L2'
const allChat = const allChat = [
    {
        senders: [
            'GiVtXApvumQgkUpkTuOGoKbe9ZE2',
            'glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S2'
        ],
        lastTalk: {
            seconds: 1666016615,
            nanoseconds: 242000000
        },
        lastMessage: 'lorem',
        glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S2: {
            uid: 'glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S2',
            userRead: true,
            fullName: 'Carina Lima'
        },
        docid: 'GiVtXApvumQgkUpkTuOGoKbe9ZE27777glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S2',
        GiVtXApvumQgkUpkTuOGoKbe9ZE2: {
            userRead: false,
            uid: 'GiVtXApvumQgkUpkTuOGoKbe9ZE2',
            fullName: 'Cristian Derick'
        },
        id: 'GiVtXApvumQgkUpkTuOGoKbe9ZE27777glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S2'
    },
    {
        docid: 'glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S27777WBZHUtoZ9DhddVmS07RL0wlvDgz1',
        WBZHUtoZ9DhddVmS07RL0wlvDgz1: {
            fullName: 'Bruce Dikinson',
            uid: 'WBZHUtoZ9DhddVmS07RL0wlvDgz1',
            userRead: false
        },
        lastTalk: {
            seconds: 1665066226,
            nanoseconds: 646000000
        },
        lastMessage: 'whatever whatever',
        glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S2: {
            uid: 'glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S2',
            userRead: true,
            fullName: 'Carina Lima'
        },
        senders: [
            'glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S2',
            'WBZHUtoZ9DhddVmS07RL0wlvDgz1'
        ],
        id: 'glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S27777WBZHUtoZ9DhddVmS07RL0wlvDgz1'
    },
    {
        lastTalk: {
            seconds: 1666189405,
            nanoseconds: 328000000
        },
        senders: [
            'glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S2',
            'glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S2'
        ],
        glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S2: {
            userRead: false,
            fullName: 'Carina Lima',
            uid: 'glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S2'
        },
        docid: 'glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S27777glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S2',
        lastMessage: 'whatever',
        id: 'glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S27777glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S2'
    },
    {
        docid: 'glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S27777ibPlTju8K2d3PlydP6sdm2T4S2L2',
        lastTalk: {
            seconds: 1666270072,
            nanoseconds: 99000000
        },
        lastMessage: 'Okay',
        senders: [
            'glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S2',
            'ibPlTju8K2d3PlydP6sdm2T4S2L2'
        ],
        ibPlTju8K2d3PlydP6sdm2T4S2L2: {
            uid: 'ibPlTju8K2d3PlydP6sdm2T4S2L2',
            userRead: true,
            fullName: 'Wanderson Santos'
        },
        glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S2: {
            userRead: false,
            fullName: 'Carina Lima',
            uid: 'glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S2'
        },
        id: 'glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S27777ibPlTju8K2d3PlydP6sdm2T4S2L2'
    }
]
```

I'm cleaning it like this to have only the data of the person I'm talking to, and alread sorting this way.

```
const fRes = allChat.map(ele => {
    if (!ele || !ele.senders || !ele.senders.includes(myUid)) return null
    const [newok] = ele.senders.filter(kv => kv !== myUid)
    let finalUser = newok
    if (ele.senders.filter(cv => cv === myUid).length === 2) finalUser = myUid
    return {
        ...ele[finalUser],
        lastMessage: ele.lastMessage,
        lastTalk: ele.lastTalk.toDate && new Date(ele.lastTalk.toDate()).getTime()
    }
}).filter(kk => kk).filter(wv => findUser(wv)).sort((a, b) => b.lastTalk - a.lastTalk)
```

response:

```
fRes = [
    {
        fullName: 'Wanderson Santos',
        uid: 'ibPlTju8K2d3PlydP6sdm2T4S2L2',
        userRead: true,
        lastMessage: 'okay',
        lastTalk: 1666270072099
    },
    {
        uid: 'glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S2',
        fullName: 'Carina Lima',
        userRead: false,
        lastMessage: 'whatever',
        lastTalk: 1666189405328
    },
    {
        uid: 'GiVtXApvumQgkUpkTuOGoKbe9ZE2',
        userRead: false,
        fullName: 'Cristian Derick',
        lastMessage: 'lorem',
        lastTalk: 1666016615242
    },
    {
        uid: 'WBZHUtoZ9DhddVmS07RL0wlvDgz1',
        userRead: false,
        fullName: 'Bruce Dikinson',
        lastMessage: 'whatever whatever',
        lastTalk: 1665066226646
    }
]
```

Now when I insert uid string on this array

```
const priority = [
    'WBZHUtoZ9DhddVmS07RL0wlvDgz1',
    'GiVtXApvumQgkUpkTuOGoKbe9ZE2'
]
```

I want a new sort based on priority, should be:

```
[
    {
        uid: 'GiVtXApvumQgkUpkTuOGoKbe9ZE2',
        userRead: false,
        fullName: 'Cristian Derick',
        lastMessage: 'lorem',
        lastTalk: 1666016615242
    },
    {
        uid: 'WBZHUtoZ9DhddVmS07RL0wlvDgz1',
        userRead: false,
        fullName: 'Bruce Dikinson',
        lastMessage: 'whatever whatever',
        lastTalk: 1665066226646
    },
    {
        fullName: 'Wanderson Santos',
        uid: 'ibPlTju8K2d3PlydP6sdm2T4S2L2',
        userRead: true,
        lastMessage: 'okay',
        lastTalk: 1666270072099
    },
    {
        uid: 'glBNAhj3RrSj5FBDwOzzSnPKN5S2',
        fullName: 'Carina Lima',
        userRead: false,
        lastMessage: 'whatever',
        lastTalk: 1666189405328
    }
]
```

Based on Last Talk and Priority
sorted by priority on top
and the rest of the users then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.sort((a, b) => { 
  const aPriority = priority.indexOf(a.uid)
  const bPriority = priority.indexOf(b.uid)
  if (aPriority !== -1 && bPriority !== -1) {
     return bPriority - aPriority
  }

  if (aPriority !== -1) {
     return -1
  }

  if (bPriority !== -1) {
     return 1
  }

  return b.lastTalk - a.lastTalk
})
```

Comment: You don't need `else` if you're returning.

Comment: Yep good point. Changing